# Not able to navigate from one Particular screen issue is only in iOS 11

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, nsarray, ios11

The app is navigating to VC1 to VC2, in VC2 "Back", "Menu" & "Submit" Button are there on click of "Submit" displaying one alert with message and "Ok" button on click of "Ok" button I'm trying to pop to VC1, code is executing but navigation is not happening.

Same is happening for "Back" & "Menu" Buttons also code is executing but not navigating to any other pages. Using Xcode 9 beta 6.

The below piece of code I'm using in my project

```
NSArray *controllersArray = [[self navigationController] viewControllers];

        for(UIViewController *controller in controllersArray)
        {
            if ([controller isKindOfClass:[ViewController1 class]])
            {
                ViewController1 *accDetailVC = (ViewController1*)controller;
                [[self navigationController] popToViewController:accDetailVC animated:YES];
                break;
            }
        }
```

working in other iOS versions except for iOS 11 beta. Please help me on this if any one is facing the same issue.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this should pop to the last controller on the stack that is of type `AccountDetailViewController`. Do you get any errors inthe console?

Comment: no i didnt get any error in console its going smooth. Can u plz check i edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue got fixed while pushing from VC1 to VC2 before I'm using `[[self navigationController] pushViewController:ctrl animated:YES]` now changed as `[[self navigationController] pushViewController:ctrl animated:NO]`

Comment: works for me 2. Still a bit confused, why the animation should be a problem.  Think it is a bug in the iOS beta, but its still included in the latest public beta. It will probably also included in the final iOS 11 version, coming next week.

Comment: I am also facing similar issue in iOS 11.0.1.
My app is working fine in <iOS 11 versions.
I have tried changing animated:No, but still issue is not solved.

Comment: facing same issue and still no luck? Any other ideas guys?